# Will Flask programs still work after Google drops 3rd party cookies from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flask, session-cookies

Google plans to eliminate the use of 3rd party cookies in Chrome this year. Are the cookies Flask uses to track sessions considered '3rd party cookies?' Will Google's change affect most Flask programs? If so, is there a workaround?

Note that the only cookie we use is Flask's session cookie. We don't use any cookies from other organizations.

I tried looking this up on the web and didn't see any relevant answers.